# What is wrong with this command?

Tags: memory-management, process, awk, watch, pmap

I'm not a software/scripting folk myself so struggling to understand what is happening here:

```
watch -n 0.2 'ps -p $(pgrep -d',' -x snmpd) -o rss= | awk '{ i += $1 } END { print i }''
```

Basically I am wanting to print the Resident Set Size value of my snmp daemon 5 times a second (for fair resolution). I then intend on building from this to redirect the output to a text file for later analysis where I can put the data into a graph for instance.

The trouble I have here is that I can run the following fine:

```
watch -n 0.2 'ps -p $(pgrep -d',' -x snmpd) -o rss'
```

However I require just the numeric value only so using *awk* to strip out everything but that value is important.

Running the first command above returns an error and I suspect due to the way *watch* is handling the single quotes, but I'm not smart enough to understand it....

Any suggestions?

Also, I have read that

```
pmap -x [pid]
```

works too, however when I run it with *snmpd's* respective PID the output is zero when clearly it is not. Any ideas on this too?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the quoted command is accurate:

```
watch -n 0.2 'ps -p $(pgrep -d',' -x snmpd) -o rss= | awk '{ i += $1 } END { print i }''
             ^                ^ ^                         ^                           ^^
             1                0 1                         0                           10
```

You've got problems with your single quotes.  The 1 indicates 'start of quote', the 0 indicates end of quote.  The following command line should work for you:

```
watch -n 0.2 'ps -p $(pgrep -d"," -x snmpd) -o rss= | awk "{ i += $1 } END { print i }"'
             ^                                                                         ^
             1                                                                         0
```

The double quotes and `$(...)` also work correctly.  The single-quoted string is sent to `watch` as a whole.  Previously, you had multiple arguments.

Note that in your working command, you have:

```
watch -n 0.2 'ps -p $(pgrep -d',' -x snmpd) -o rss'
             ^                ^ ^                 ^
             1                0 1                 0
```

Now, because the character between the middle '01' is a comma, not a blank, the shell continues to give `watch` a single argument, but it doesn't contain the quotes.  What `watch` gets as its third argument is:

```
ps -p $(pgrep -d, -xsnmpd) -o rss
```

With your `awk`-line, 1watch` gets multiple arguments:

```
ps -p $(pgrep -d, -x snmpd) -o rss= | awk {
i
+=
$1
}
END
{
print
i
}
```

And it doesn't know what to do with the excess.  (NB: The value of `$1` would be the shell's current `$1` (possibly an empty string, in which case the argument corresponding to `$1` would be omitted.)

---

This variant, with a backslash before the `$1` in the `awk` script, seemed to work for me (when I looked for a program which actually was running — `snmpd` was not running on the machine where I tested, and things fell apart because of that):

```
sh -c 'ps -p $(pgrep -d"," -x snmpd) -o rss= | awk "{ i += \$1 } END { print i }"'
```

If you think there's any danger that there is no `snmpd` process, then you need to do things a little less compactly.  That's the command I tested; you can put the `watch -n 0.2` in place of the `sh -c`.  But note that the man page for [`watch`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_watch.htm) does explicitly say:

> Note that `command` is given to "`sh -c`" which means that you may need to use extra quoting to get the desired effect.

That was very accurate!

If you prefer to stick with single quotes, you could try:

```
watch -n 0.2 'ps -p $(pgrep -d"," -x snmpd) -o rss= | awk '\''{ i += $1 } END { print i }'\'
```

The idea behind the `'\''` motif is that the first single quote terminates the current single-quoted string; the backslash single quote adds an actual single quote, and the last single quote starts a new single-quoted string.  The `'\'` at the end could also be written `'\'''`, but the last two single quotes are redundant, so I left them out.

Comment: Thanks for your effort JL. I like the explanation and suggestion of the double quotes which makes sense. *awk* however doesn't like the use of the double quotes though... I'm lost on this one.

Comment: I'm tolerably sure that the diagnosis of what went wrong is on target.  It is harder to be sure about the replacement.  You're saying it doesn't work.  But the `$(pgrep...)` stuff worked OK.  The man page for [`watch`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_watch.htm) says: _Note that_ command _is given to "sh -c" which means that you may need to use extra quoting to get the desired effect._

Comment: OK. Without giving the command to *watch*, *awk* does not like the use of the double quotes. So when passed to watch *awk* is still producing the error. That said, your single quote variant works fine. Many thanks.